# Printing a value of object to console automatically in c#

Tags: c#

I am not sure if this has already been asked since I am not sure how to phrase this properly.

```
class Program {
  public static void Main (string[] args) 
  {
    Console.WriteLine ("Start:");
    Example thing = new Example();
    Console.WriteLine(thing);
  }
}
```

This would write the type of object:

```
>> Example
```

Whereas I would like it to print a value that the Example object would have.

Is this possible and, if so, how would I do this?

EDIT:
I would like it to output like this (if "hello" was the contents of the variable I want to output):

```
Console.WriteLine(thing);
```

Output:

```
>> hello
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method. Did you even searched a bit? This question was asked so many times before.

Comment: Create a override method ToString() in Example class. Return rewuired data from the method then you can call that statement to print.

Comment: For me, the answer is in the 3rd Google result: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ThomasWeller That duplicate is quite poor, as serializing to JSON is quite overkill here.

Comment: Google for: "write object to console c#" immediately yields many examples on how to do this.

Comment: it seems you are not clear about what value an `object` has. `thing` is of type `Example` and what you want to print out is a `string`. So these two are different types! `thing` cannot (by definition) have the value of `"hello"`! either a property in the class `Example` can be of type `string` and have the value `"hello"` or `thing` needs to be of type `string`. A third possibility is that you override the `ToString` method and simply return `return "hello";` from the method.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: do not only look at the accepted answer. 3+ other answers tell to override the ToString() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to override and implement the `object.ToString()` method, e.g.

```
public class Example {
    ...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.SomeProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Also, is it possible to do this with integers and other variable types?

Comment: Most native types will already have a `.ToString()` implementation, so yes you could use `return this.IntProperty.ToString();` or even use string interpolation `return $"The value is: {this.IntProperty}";`.